# Why isn't the touchscreen pressure reading being put into use by Android?

Tags: stock-android, touchscreen, sensors

Just now I discovered the "Pointer Location" dev app on Android, which tells how much pressure is being applied on the point on the touchscreen. They even have it since Android 1.0.

I know there may not be dedicated pressure sensors and it is just an estimate depending on point size.

I am saying that why didn't or couldn't Android implement "Force Touch" in Android phones? They have the pressure readings ready. They even have the method which when called gives the pressure.

P.S. I am running LineageOS unofficial build for my OnePlus One.

Answer (score 3):

Don't run to conclusions early - some [Huawei](http://www.androidcentral.com/hands-force-touch-huawei-mate-s)/[Meizu](http://www.meizu.com/en/products/pro6/3dpress.html)/[ZTE](http://www.techtimes.com/articles/94274/20151012/zte-adds-axon-mini-force-touch-watch-flagship-lineup.htm) flagships has it, sometimes referred to as "3D Press" or other names.

Ultimately the feature is worthless - it requires 3rd-party apps to integrate well, but since Android doesn't have a native implementation of it (yet), there's no way apps could adapt to all the proprietary standards raised by different manufacturers. The app support situation and the sales of the above phones proves the point.

This situation is quite similar to what fingerprint scanners have experienced on Android before Marshmallow, except that it's of even fewer actual use than it.

Comment: And don't get started on how _Apple_ did it - as a sole controller of its ecosystem, it can forcefully push _any_ standard it wants.

Comment: Agreed sir, but what about any other apps, such as entertainment or games etc... Or even some utilities may be able to use the pressure readings to perform a task, right? I mean it exists... So why even app devs have not used it?

Comment: @NiranjanDixit What exists? If you mean the pointer location option in Developer Options, no it does not sense pressure - the PRS value changes with the _area_ your finger lays on the screen, not pressure (try applying more force but still use the fingertip). How is the phone supposed to support it _without_ corresponding hardware?

Comment: Right, that's why I said "estimate" or emulated value.

Comment: @NiranjanDixit Well, ultimately it still boils down to whether it's stable enough and of enough use to warrant extra effort put into development. See how many apps, especially games, on iOS that haven't adopted Force Touch.

Comment: Thank you. I understand now. "Rant" is over. It's like an extra feature... Not very essential but exists if need be

Comment: @NiranjanDixit Yeah that's it. If it's as essential as fingerprint scanners, Android will certainly up its pace to add it, instead of only adding the popup menu (not even the actual force touch function itself) in Nougat.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that some kind of estimation of the pressure is there doesn't mean that it works well. It is better to stick to features that are more reliable. Half-baked options are not something welcome in operating systems.

Also, don't you think this would be copying Apple's idea?

Comment: Is copying a competitor's idea a bad thing? If no manufacturers copied their competitors ideas we would have pretty featureless devices today

Comment: Yes but, as I said, the measurements are not precise enough to make this an official feature.