# How do I know if my phone's touchscreen supports Electro Magnetic Resonance (EMR) technology?

Tags: touchscreen, touch, stylus, drawing, autodesk-sketchbook

I am planning to start sketching on my Android Device - Nokia 6.1 Plus - using Apps like AutoDesk SketchBook, Bamboo Paper or Adobe Sketch. For that I am thinking of buying a stylus - [Noris Digital](https://www.staedtler.com/dk/en/discover/noris-digital/#).

Noris Digital only works if the touchscreen has electromagnetic resonance (EMR) digitizer. I am unable to find out if my mobile device has that feature. Any idea how do I find that out.

If my phone does not support that then can I use Wacom's [Bamboo Tip](https://www.wacom.com/en-us/products/stylus/bamboo-tip), again the issue is finding if its supported or not. Moreover this does not have pressure levels. How do I know which pressure level and palm rejecting stylus will work for my phone.

Comment: Related on Android's touch pressure: [Why isn't the touchscreen pressure reading being put into use by Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/167320/44325) which basically says "*Android doesn't support **real** touch pressure natively and instead approximating the area of the touch*", which leaves to the drawing app to communicate with the stylus directly for pressure value (if possible). (Also related on GraphicDesign.SE: [Android tablet vs Wacom tablet](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/100659))

Comment: Maybe this [app](Complete information about your CPU, GPU, battery, camera, network and OS.

Available on Google Play: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=flar2.devcheck) would tell you if it is supported?

Answer (score 2):

If you scroll down on your linked page to the Noris Digital stylus, there is a section on compatibility which links to [this pdf document](https://e.staedtlercdn.com/fileadmin/user_upload/Product/PDF/Compatibility_Noris_digital.1585894357.pdf)

The only mobile device I recognize are the Samsung mobile devices supporting S-Pen.

Your alternate Bamboo Tip link also has a compatibility document: https://www.wacom.com/en-us/comp which lists support on all of Bamboo's devices. The Bamboo Tip section lists a number of Android devices: like the Google Nexus 5X, Amazon Fire HD 10 (7th generation), Samsung Galaxy S8 as well other manufacturers. This tells me that the Bamboo Tip is capacitive and should work with most phones (unless using the older resistive screen for speciality devices).

As to how the Bamboo Tip can handle palm rejection, I can't be sure, but expect that it is still limited to what the device is capable of, as app developers typically depend on the system to handle errant touches.

Comment: I did read the pdf document. It's not possible for them to test each and every smartphone out there. I think they just have a sample of supported devices. In the pdf itself they mention that if the device has EMR technology then you should be good. So I am focusing on that. How common is it? And how do I know if my phone has it. My research tells me that it is used for pressure sensitive strokes. So is there a way to find that out from a smartphone itself?

Comment: EMR to my knowledge is a pretty specialized tech for phones. See [How do Samsung S-Pen work](https://www.androidauthority.com/break-it-down-how-does-the-s-pen-work-154435/) and that tech has to be licensed to manufacturer from Wacom . Even the FAQ at the Noris Digital site calls it 'Wacom EMR' and makes a comparison to 'S-Pen'. Remember if the device has a Pen with pressure sensitivity that is a marketing point for the device and so would be a candidate.